# Create a view where a value is shown as variable

Tags: mysql, view

I have a view that I need to extend with a value from the select;

```
select 
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`submit_time` AS `submit_time`,
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`form_name` AS `form_name`,
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_name` AS `field_name`,
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_value` AS `field_value`,
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_order` AS `field_order`,
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`file` AS `file`,`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`processed` AS `processed` 
from `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits` 
where isnull(`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`processed`)
```

The variable I need to show called 'file_name' should be the contents of 'field_value' if the 'field_name' is equal to 'File'

Is this possible and if so, how would I do this?

Comment: Could you post your current `create view` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You could use IF() in the field list:

```
select 
   `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`submit_time` AS `submit_time`,
   `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`form_name` AS `form_name`,
   `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_name` AS `field_name`,
   `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_value` AS `field_value`,
   `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_order` AS `field_order`,
   `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`file` AS `file`,
   `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`processed` AS `processed`,
   IF(`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_name`='File', `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_value`, NULL) AS `file_name`
from `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits` 
where isnull(`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`processed`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` statement to get your expected result. Also one issue in your WHERE clause, the condition should be `columnname IS NULL`.

```
SELECT
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`submit_time` AS `submit_time`,
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`form_name` AS `form_name`,
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_name` AS `field_name`,
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_value` AS `field_value`,
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_order` AS `field_order`,
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`file` AS `file`, 
`mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`processed` AS `processed`
CASE WHEN `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_name` = 'File' THEN `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`field_value`
     ELSE '' 
     END AS `file_name`
FROM `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits` 
WHERE `mc_cf7dbplugin_submits`.`processed` IS NULL
```